# Doctrine ORM querying by value object throws a semantic error (mappings for insert work)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Does anyone know how to query the database using a value object (embedded field)?

I get the following error if when trying to get the count of records using query builder:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 55 near 'email = :ema': Error: Class
Domain\User\Entity\User has no field or association named email
```

The repository method is:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Domain\User\Entity\User;
use Domain\User\Exception\UserNotFoundException;
use Domain\User\Repository\UserRepository;
use Domain\User\ValueObject\Email;
use Domain\User\ValueObject\UserId;

class DoctrineUserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserRepository
{
    /** {@inheritdoc} */
    public function isEmailUnique(Email $email)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

        $count = (int) $qb
            ->select($qb->expr()->count('u'))
            ->where('u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('email', $email->getValue())
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult()
        ;

        return 0 === $count;
    }
}
```

The mappings work (records are inserted, db schema updated).

The `User` mappings:

```
Domain\User\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: user
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\DoctrineUserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: guid
            generator:
                strategy: NONE
    embedded:
        email:
            class: Domain\User\ValueObject\Email
            columnPrefix: false
        fullName:
            class: Domain\User\ValueObject\FullName
            columnPrefix: false
        password:
            class: Domain\User\ValueObject\PasswordHash
            columnPrefix: false
    fields:
        createdAt:
            type: datetime
            column: created_at
```

The `Email` value object mapping:

```
Domain\User\ValueObject\Email:
    type: embeddable
    fields:
        value:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
            column: email
```

Using the following versions of libraries (`composer show -i`):

```
doctrine/annotations                 v1.2.4
doctrine/cache                       v1.4.1
doctrine/collections                 v1.3.0
doctrine/common                      v2.5.0
doctrine/dbal                        v2.5.1
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             v1.4.0
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       v1.0.1
doctrine/inflector                   v1.0.1
doctrine/instantiator                1.0.4 
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1
doctrine/orm                         v2.5.0
symfony/symfony                      2.7.x-dev 84ce2c5
```

User entity:

```
<?php

namespace Domain\User\Entity;

use Domain\User\Event\UserSignedUp;
use Domain\User\ValueObject\Email;
use Domain\User\ValueObject\FullName;
use Domain\User\ValueObject\PasswordHash;
use Domain\User\ValueObject\UserId;
use SimpleBus\Message\Recorder\ContainsRecordedMessages;
use SimpleBus\Message\Recorder\PrivateMessageRecorderCapabilities;

class User implements ContainsRecordedMessages
{
    use PrivateMessageRecorderCapabilities;

    /** @var UserId */
    private $id;

    /** @var Email */
    private $email;

    /** @var FullName */
    private $fullName;

    /** @var Password */
    private $password;

    /** @var \DateTime */
    private $createdAt;

    public function __construct(UserId $id, Email $email, FullName $fullName, PasswordHash $password)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->fullName = $fullName;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();

        $this->record(new UserSignedUp($this->id));
    }

    /** @return UserId */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /** @return Email */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /** @return FullName */
    public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->fullName;
    }

    /** @return Password */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /** @return \DateTime */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }
}
```

Email value object:

```
<?php

namespace Domain\User\ValueObject;

use Domain\Core\Validation\Assert;

final class Email
{
    /** @var string */
    private $value;

    /** @param string $value */
    public function __construct($value)
    {
        Assert::notEmpty($value);
        Assert::email($value);

        $this->value = $value;
    }

    /** @return string */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that comparing Value Objects by properties is not fully supported yet, which is why you have to specify which field you're targeting.

Try writing the query like this and give it a try:

```
    $qb
        ->select($qb->expr()->count('u'))
        ->where('u.email.value = :email')
        ->setParameter('email', $email->getValue())
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult()
    ;
```

Take a notice at `u.email.value`.